# How to get data from XML files into business objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-xml, linq-to-xsd

I need to build a view in my MVC 2 application that allows a user to upload an XML file.  The XML files will conform to an XSD.  I need to parse the XML and extract data to populate C# objects that will then be sent off to a web service.

My question is...since I know the exact "format" of the XML files, because of the XSD, is there some easier way to "move" the data in the XML files into my business objects?

I read about some Linq-to-XSD project, but it appears to have been abandoned.  Linq-to-XML doesn't seen very helpful, since I still have to "walk" through the entire XML document to get all the data.

Surely there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/

here is a linq to xsd project on codeplex

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ_to_XSD.aspx

another on code project

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LINQToEverythingLINQToXSDAddsMoreLINQiness.aspx

and scott hanselmen talks about this. Between these links(no pun intended) you should be alright